# Delete entry from /etc/fstab using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am scripting a solution wherein, when a shared drive is removed from the server, we need to remove the entry from fstab as well.

What I have done till now :

```
MP="${ServerAddress}:${DirectoryPath} ${MountPoint} nfs defaults 0 0"

while read line; do
                if [ "${MP}" = "${line}" ]; then
                    sed "/${line}/d"
                fi
done < /etc/fstab
```

this is giving an error  >> sed: 1: "/servername.net...": command I expects \ followed by text

Please suggest on this can be deleted.

PS: I am running this as a part of the script, so i dont have to run this individually. While running with the suggested options, I am able to delete.. but during the script, this does not work and gives that error. People commenting on the " or the formatting, its just that I cannot copy from there since that is a remote through terminal server.

Comment: This won't modify the file. You would only need: `sed -i "/${line}/d" /etc/fstab`. No need for a loop.

Comment: You have updated the original question after our replies, but you're still missing one key point: You don't need the `while` loop, nor the `if` test: `sed` already loops on all the lines of the file and it already tests if such lines match the given pattern. I would suggest having a look at its man page and at some tutorials/examples on the Net.

Comment: I have just updated the Comment inside PS:.. Also, there are multiple entries inside the fstab with same inputs.. thats why While loop..
Also, this is just a part of the script.. not an individual command.. The whole script is doing some more stuff than just deleting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sed -i.bak "\@^$SERVERADDR:$DIRPATH@d" /etc/fstab
```

After setting meaningful values for SERVERADDR and DIRPATH. That line will also make a backup of the old file (named `fstab.bak`). But since `/etc/fstab` is such an important file, please make sure to have more backups handy.

Let me point out that you only need that single line, no while loop, no script!

Comment: I agree except that the directory path will contain slashes, and that will wreck the search pattern.  You need to choose an improbable character such as `@` and use `"\@^$SERVERADDR:$DIRPATH@d"`.  Also, embed the whole pattern in double quotes, in case there are spaces in it (as there are in the question).

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that! I have switched to `@`. You seem to suggest to escape the leading one but not the trailing one, is that correct?

Comment: That's correct; the backslash is a key part of the syntax. The POSIX definition of [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) says:  _In a context address, the construction "`\cBREc`", where c is any character other than `<backslash>` or `<newline>`, shall be identical to "`/BRE/`". If the character designated by c appears following a `<backslash>`, then it shall be considered to be that literal character, which shall not terminate the BRE. For example, in the context address "`\xabc\xdefx`", the second `x` stands for itself, so that the BRE is "`abcxdef`"._

Comment: Good to know. I seldom use this `sed` syntax, and when I do a simple slash works fine. I mostly use `sed` for substitutions, and no backslash is required there. Thanks for the clarification, I learned something myself from this question :).

Comment: There are multiple entry with the same name in the fstab which needs to be deleted. thats why the While loop

Comment: In that case I guess the pattern `${MP}` should change in the loop, but it doesn't, so I don't see how that loop can delete more than a single line. Unless they are exactly identical, of course, but I see no use for that in `fstab`. Anyway you can just run `sed` as described multiple times or with a more generic pattern that matches all the lines you need to delete.

Comment: Also, this is just a part of the script.. the whole script is doing many other stuff as well.

Comment: This command was able to echo the right thing, but nothing actually happened inside the fstab file.. that remains the same as before.

Comment: I guess you're missing the `-i` option. Please read our answers carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the shell is case-sensitive and expects `"` as double quotes and not `”` (a problem now fixed in the question).  You need to configure your editor not to capitalize words randomly for you (also now fixed).  Note that experimenting on system configuration files is A Bad Idea™.  Make a copy of the file and experiment on the copy.  Only when you're sure that the script works on the copy do you risk the live file.  And then you make a backup of the live file before making the changes.  (And avoid doing the experimenting as root if at all possible; that limits the damage you can do.)

Your script as written might as well not use `sed`.  Change the comparison to `!=` and simply use `echo "$line"` to echo the lines you want to standard output.

```
MP="${ServerAddress}:${DirectoryPath} ${MountPoint} nfs defaults 0 0"

while read line; do
    if [ "${MP}" != "${line}" ]; then
    echo "$line"
    fi
done < /etc/fstab
```

Alternatively, you can use `sed` in a single command.  The only trick is that the pattern probably contains slashes, so the `\@` notation says 'use `@` as the search marker'.

```
MP="${ServerAddress}:${DirectoryPath} ${MountPoint} nfs defaults 0 0"
sed -e "\@$MP@d" /etc/fstab
```

If you have GNU `sed`, when you're satisfied with that, you can add the `-i.bak` option to overwrite the `/etc/fstab` file (preserving a copy of the original in `/etc/fstab.bak`).  Or use `-i $(date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S')` to get a backup extension that is the current date/time.  Or use version control on the file.